# How to recover data from ubuntu when unable to load

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, data-recovery

Recently, I upgraded my desktop hardware to i3 4th gen processor, ram, motherboard and new SSD. I had ubuntu installed earlier on 320GB HDD and I've installed a fresh windows 8 OS on new 120gb SSD and made this primary. However, when I tried accessing ubuntu from old hard disk it is loading grub loader correctly but got stuck with a black screen. So I tried recovery mode which also got stuck with the message "ndinswrapper couldn't load driver netr28ux" and several other such kind of messages. Though I'm no longer planning to use ubuntu os but I just want to recover data. I tried ubuntu repair disk which also made no difference. When I tried accessing that disk from windows 8 using disk management it shows no volume name or file system type.

Disk Management Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows cannot natively understand the format of a Linux disk. So you have a number of options.

The simplest is to get hold of a Live CD version of Linux and boot from it. All of your disks should then be visible and you can copy between them.

You could also install VirtualBox, set up a Linux VM with access to the physical partition.

Finally, you could install an application that will allow access to Linux Ext3 partitions.